# Write large dataframe in Excel Pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, xlsxwriter

I have a dataframe which contains data between 5,50,000, to 9,00,000 rows and 10 columns
I read the data from postgtresql and converted the data into dataframe which took few secondas.
However when trying to write data in excel it took more than 1 hour to write

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('filepath/file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='My Report', startrow=8, index=False, header=False)

Is there any way we can insert huge dataframe in excel format in few seconds?

Comment: have you tried another engine like `openpyxl`?

Comment: you're probably limited by your hardware. I'd recommend trying `to_csv()` method, it is much faster than `to_excel()`, and excel can read CSV files

Comment: 5,50,000 ? What is this ? 5 000 000 ? 550 000 ? Moreover, writing millions of rows with ten columns is not feasible in "few seconds". Even spark would not be able to do it that fast.

Comment: Note that there is a limit for the total number of rows and columns on a microsoft excel worksheet. According to [the official source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3), it is 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns for a worksheet of a xlsx file.

Answer (score 0):

First you can use the csv format instea, is faster:

```
df.to_csv('filepath/file.csv', index=False)
```

If it's mandatory the excel format you can write to the file using lower chunks like:

```
chunk_size = 10000  # Adjust this based on your system's memory capacity
num_chunks = len(df) // chunk_size + 1

with pd.ExcelWriter('filepath/file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    for i in range(num_chunks):
        start_idx = i * chunk_size
        end_idx = min((i + 1) * chunk_size, len(df))
        chunk_df = df.iloc[start_idx:end_idx]
        chunk_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='My Report', startrow=start_idx + 8, index=False, header=False)
```

If you can use the **openpyxl** engine:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('filepath/file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='My Report', startrow=8, index=False, header=False)
```